# What to do with questions that are about algorithm, not a particular language?

Tags: discussion

I tend to browse SO with filters for specific languages, and often see questions tagged only with that language but whose main query really is 'how to write an algorithm to do X?' .  Conversely,  for example, I recently read a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736753/numpy-rank-within-columns-of-2d-array) tagged only with languages (python and scipy) but was actually about matrix sorting algorithms.  The question and solution are applicable across pretty much any language, so what can be done to make it easier to track a question?  Just load it up with more tags? And if so, is there some way to encourage question-posters to list not only language but also "process" tags?

Comment: There's a pretty good chance that such a question would be better suited for Computer Science or Mathematics, rather than SO.  Such a question may no longer be a *specific* programming problem.

Comment: don't we have an `algorithm` tag?

Comment: @Servy OP asks about `python` and `scipy`. This is where programming related stackexchange domains are interleaving and SO split strikes again.

Comment: SO is big enough to support multiple answers about the same algorithm, specific for any major language tag.  Whomever searches for such a question is almost always interested in a solution for his favorite language, not some opaque Wikipedia-style article with pseudo code.  A Fisher-Yates shuffle is a good example, existing answers cover it for any language.

Comment: A question might *have* a more general answer, but that doesn't mean the asker cares about how to do it in other languages or the underlying CS principles, or would necessarily understand an explanation that didn't involve their chosen tool. Not everything has to be a general theoretical reference.

Comment: There's a [tag:language-agnostic] tag

Comment: @Servy If it passes the low quality filter first. Also, isn't Comp Sci supposed to be for higher level computer science questions, kind of like how MathOverflow is for fairly high level math? I'm not sure where I got that idea from, but that was my understanding.

Comment: @jpmc26: As I understand it, Comp Sci is to Math.SE as Theoretical Comp Sci is to Math Overflow.  But I'm not active on any of those four sites, so I may be wrong too.

Comment: If the question is about an algorithm itself, then I think @Servy is right. If the question is about how to _implement_ an algorithm (presumably in the tagged language), then I think it's on-topic for SO. However, I also think a question like that would need to show what OP had tried and identify pretty specifically what's not working. Otherwise I would very likely vote to close, probably as "not clear what you're asking" or "too broad".