# Do pure algorithmic questions belong in SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

I  know that SO is for programmers, not mathematicians. But any good programmer should be comfortable with mathematics. I have seen that when people ask questions about algorithms (running time, correctness) but the algorithms are not written in a specific language but rather pseudo code, people tend to flag them as off topic.

But pure algorithmic analysis seems relevant to programming (at least to me), since things like sorting algorithms, Djkistra, O notation are all very important and common when programming. So it seems like a grey area to me, and one that I personally (and biased) would like to be tolerated.

What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Try [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That's not the topic at hand at all.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286090/questions-on-algorithm-complexity-not-related-to-any-particular-code and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345467/high-level-algorithm-engineering-questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281646/what-to-do-with-questions-that-are-about-algorithm-not-a-particular-language

Comment: Sure, as long as they don't continually go over the same, miserable ground, eg 'What is big O for my nested loops', AKA 'do my homework':(   Similarly, sorting algorithms are hugely well Googleable, and developers should not need to ask about them here under most circumstances.

Comment: What if you wanna know about an in place implementation of merge sort that should be general enough to be implemented in most languages?

Comment: If you're writing CSS, what do you care about runtimes or algorithms?

Comment: Questions about algorithms are *explicitly* on-topic on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Ask your question on StackOverflow if it relates to language/implementation but ask it on Computer Science if it relates to abstract analysis.

Comment: If only I could ask questions :C

Comment: @Makogan: That's up to you. You basically have to improve all your existing questions. If you don't see any further potential for improvement, then you have to improve your question asking skills. This is hard work, but there is no other way around it...

Comment: I thought making good answers could help :C.

Comment: @Makogan: As far as I understood, it helps, but only to a limited amount. You also have to prove that you can ask good questions. Improving all your questions might be the quicker way to get out of the ban...

Answer (score -10):

There's a hard requisite for questions being on topic for SO:

> a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**

A algo question is rarely (I would say never) unique to software development.

Comment: Really? How many people do you think are going to run, say, TSP solvers in their head or on paper? What field uses divide-and-conquer algorithms beyond the most trivial except software? But in principle I think there are a reasonable number of algorithm questions to be asked on SO about different aspects of various TSP approaches. (And, of course, many similar questions should really go on CS or TCS instead.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy again, that's irrelevant: you don't have a question unique to software development, you don't have a SO question. Simple. Why you want it so complex?

Comment: So why are my examples *not* unique to software development? (That was literally my only point: that there definitely do exist such examples that are for all practical purposes unique to software, and thus unique to software development.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Again: not unique to software development, not within the scope of SO. Do you want to go back to the time where "X for programmers" or "X in programming" was valid? I bet you don't. Enforcing this part of the scope in the help center will prevent some of the ugly from the dark times to come back.

Comment: OK. Help me out here. How, precisely, is "TSP solver consideration XYZ for programmers" *at all different* from "PHP function usage problem ABC for programmers"? The latter is of course SO's bread and butter. I haven't the foggiest idea why you are making this seemingly bizarre assertion that algorithms that are only useful in making software can, in any meaningful way, *not* be "unique to software development". Why don't I have any idea? Because you haven't begun to explain it at all! It's as though you think it should be dead obvious that *of course* this is the new boat programming.